# wpf how to make a framwork element store a drawing visual as a bit map and display that on render?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make my framework element, signalgraph, display the signal (a DrawingVisual) as a bitmap and then render the bitmap when WPF goes through a rendering pass. I'm guessing I override onRender for the FrameworkElement, but I'm not sure. I just want to try converting everything to a bitmap because I think the program renders slow because there are too many lines, and saving it to a bit map would hopefully improve performance.

As a test, I tried to add a SkyBlue Rectangle to the framework element, but it is not displaying.

I create a rectangle that inherits from Shape, which inherits from Visual. I then use the RenderTargetBitmap class to render the visual, and then set the output render of the rendertargetbitmap as  the source of an Image. Image is a framework element, so I then just add it to the visual collection in the hopes that it will display, but nothing appears.

```
    Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();
    myRect.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    myRect.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.SkyBlue;
    myRect.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myRect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    myRect.Height = 200;
    myRect.Width = 200;
    BitmapImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(1000, 1000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    BitmapImage.Render(myRect);
    GraphImage = new Image();
    GraphImage.Source = BitmapImage;
    visuals.Add(GraphImage); //visuals is a VisualCollection
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any ideas or alternatives that I might try to save the lines drawn on the canvas to a bit map would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out the [BitmapCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcachebrush%28VS.100%29.aspx)? I believe this is what you're after and it's auto-magical.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is major factor, I would suggest you instead of going with WPF shapes, try [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whose performance is very good compare to WPF shapes.

It's very easy to use and integrate to project. Simply you need to `create one VisulHost say Canvas which will hold VisualCollection of all drawing visual`, you want to draw. Override few these two FrameworkElement members - `GetVisualChild` and `VisualChildrenCount`.

You can read more about here on MSDN - [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also can refer to this for already available working solution - [WPF DrawTools](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools).